# OpenCL Profiling Info Unavailable for Marker Commands

Tags: opencl

Using AMDs APP OpenCL implementation with JOCL bindings, I'm trying to create a generic bracketing profiler using Java automatic resource management.  The basic idea is:

```
class Timer implements AutoCloseable {
    ...
    Timer { 
        ...
        clEnqueueMarker( commandQueue, startEvent );
    }

    void close() {
        cl_event stopEvent = new cl_event();
        clEnqueueMarker( commandQueue, stopEvent );
        clFinish( commandQueue );
        ... calculate and output times ...
    } 
}
```

My problem is that profiling information is not available for the marker command events (stopEvent and startEvent).  This is despite a) setting CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE on the command queue and b) flushing and waiting on the command queue and verifying that the stop and start events are CL_COMPLETE with no errors.

So my question is, is profiling supported on marker commands in AMD OpenCL?  If not, is it explicitly disallowed by the spec (I found nothing to this effect)? 
Thanks.

Comment: What value does clGetEventProfilingInfo(...) return? Does it return CL_SUCCESS?

Comment: It's returning CL_PROFILING_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE.  I also queried the event status with clGetEventInfo to verify that the event is CL_COMPLETE, it is.  Hence my confusion regarding profiling support in marker commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've rechecked the spec and it seems to me that what you get is normal (though I've never paid much attention to that detail previously). In the section 5.12 about profiling, the standard states:

> This section describes profiling of OpenCL functions that are enqueued
>   as commands to a command-queue. The specific functions being
>   referred to are: *clEnqueue{Read|Write|Map}Buffer,
>   clEnqueue{Read|Write}BufferRect, clEnqueue{Read|Write|Map}Image,
>   clEnqueueUnmapMemObject, clEnqueueCopyBuffer, clEnqueueCopyBufferRect,
>   clEnqueueCopyImage, clEnqueueCopyImageToBuffer,
>   clEnqueueCopyBufferToImage, clEnqueueNDRangeKernel , clEnqueueTask and
>   clEnqueueNativeKernel.*

So the clEnqueueMarker() function is not in the list, and I guess the CL_PROFILING_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE value returned makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and it seems to work now. Tested on Windows 10 with an AMD 7870 and on Linux with Nvidias Titan Black and Titan X cards.

The OpenCL 1.2 specs still contain the paragraph @CaptainObvious quoted. The `clEnqueueMarker` function is still missing, but I can get profiling information without a problem.

The start and end times on marker events are always equal, which makes a lot of sense.

Btw. `clEnqueueMarker` is [deprecated in OpenCL 1.2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/deprecated.html) and should be replaced with [`clEnqueueMarkerWithWaitList`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMarkerWithWaitList.html).